# Is "super stable" correct English?

Tags: grammaticality

A user [quoted one my posts](https://www.lowendtalk.com/discussion/comment/2932809/#Comment_2932809) on another forum, and said I should have used the word "very" instead of "super". He also said I am corrupting the English language by doing so.

Sentence:

> I have a AlphaRacks VPS on QN. It's been super stable so far. I've
>   only had it for around a month though.

I am not an English major at all, and so I'm curious if this is true and should I stay away from combining the words `super` and `stable`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's in an informal register, but it communicates effectively.

Comment: I see. Definitely going to be reading about that. Thanks!

Comment: Superman's horse is being kept in the Super Stable.

Comment: I wouldn't say that "very" was a formal equivalent for "super": I would say that the true equivalent was "exceptionally". However "super" is a much simpler and vibrant way of saying it. I'd use "super" in informal speech and writing and "exceptionally" in formal writing and presentations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- > It's been **super stable** so far.

**super**  infml [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/super) & [TDF](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/super)
​

> excellent; extremely good, great, extreme, first rate, very large

So someone objects to the use of an English word (yours) and rather you use their English word. Super is effective and your use to my sense is good and proper!

Comment: Wow, might be a  grudge that user has against me? Just weird because I've never engaged him/her before. But I'm glad I double checked  about this, thank you. Can't upvote, but will select this as the answer.

Comment: @JohnMiller Do note the **infml** note in the quote above. Other dictionaries - among them New Oxford American Dictionary and Collins - also tag the use of *super* as adjective as informal. Some would say *very* informal (super informal?). So it might be good, but proper it is not.

Comment: In this context, "super" is used as an adverb (modifying the adjective "stable"), not as an adjective.

Comment: @sumelic: So, if it is an adjverb, maybe we should use **superly stable**.  After all, **suberb stable** would be wrong, and we would use **suberbly stable**...

Comment: @GEdgar: It's an adverb, but both the adverb and adjective "super" come from a Latin preposition. In formal English, "super" mostly isn't used either as an adverb or as an adjective, but as a prefix (e.g. *supernatural, supersonic*). I don't think "superly" is used either in formal or colloquial English, so I wouldn't recommend using it (my spellchecker underlines it).

Answer (score 0):

It’s an informal adverb in this case. Just as “extremely “

Comment: Thank you. Seems like it should be fine then,  I just chose a different adverb